# how to end an Android boardcastreceiver process

Tags: android, process, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a boardcast listener that is listening to alarms my app set previously.
I need it able to receive the alarm even my app exits. So I use an other proecess like this

```
        <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote"></receiver>
```

But from DBMS I see the process after it code returned. I am wondering if there is a way to end this process

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Context.unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29)